# Sqlite Update query syntax error

Tags: android, sqlite

whenever I try to update details I get  syntax error near nRating

```
 public void addRating(String name, String nDate, String nRating,
    String nComment)
{

SQLiteDatabase data = this.getWritableDatabase();

Cursor query = data.rawQuery("update Station Set " + " date " + " = "
    + nDate + "," + " rating " + nRating + "," + " comments "
    + nComment + " Where Stationname " + " = " + name, null);
query.close();

}
```

Comment: You are missng "=" after rating and comments.  `update Station Set " + " date " + " = "
    + nDate + "," + " rating = " + nRating + "," + " comments ="
    + nComment + " where Stationname " + " = " + name, null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue of course is that you're missing the `=` as @Ranjith pointed out in the comments.

In addition, for an `Update` query you should use `execSQL` instead of `rawQuery`.

So, no need for a `Cursor`, and also close the database when you're done with it.

```
public void addRating(String name, String nDate, String nRating,
    String nComment)
{

   SQLiteDatabase data = this.getWritableDatabase();

   data.execSQL("update Station Set " + " date = "
    + nDate + "," + " rating = " + nRating + "," + " comments = "
    + nComment + " where Stationname = '" + name + "'" );

    data.close(); //close the database

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missng "=" after rating and comments.

Change to as below:

```
Cursor query = data.rawQuery("Update Station Set " + " date " + " = " + nDate + "," + " rating = " + nRating + "," + " comments =" + nComment + " where Stationname " + " = " + name, null);
```